# C get ip by hostname

Tags: c, sockets, dns

Does anyone know how to get IP from a hostname to use in a c socket? (winsock)
I have a socket but when I use: 
`sock.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("example.no-ip.org");` it won't work...

Comment: "it wont works..." is not a valid reason to start asking questions. What is the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting host to ip by sockaddr\_in gethostname etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444197/converting-host-to-ip-by-sockaddr-in-gethostname-etc)

Comment: well when it compiles, it is no errors... but in time to stalish socket connection, it won't work like my own ip works... it won't stablish a conection...

Answer (score 1):

[`inet_addr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) just processes textually written already-numeric IP numbers. You will want to translate the domain name first with [`getaddrinfo().`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The function `inet_addr()` only works on numbered ip addresses, like 1.2.3.4.
To find the ip address for a generic host name, you need the function `gethostbyname()`.
See for instance [this documentation of Microsoft with example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Or, since it is deprecated, the function `getaddrinfo()`.

Oh, and since you're on Windows, don't forget to call `WSAStartup()` beforehand.