# Winsock code not working

Tags: c++, winsock

I have finished my c++ tutorial and went to winsock, but still a bit new to the subject. I made a client code that tried to connect to a website using port 80 (http) but whenever i run it i get an error code 10049 and it doesn't connect to the server. Here is the code..

Defenitions.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

//Prototypes:
WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA info;
SOCKET hSocket;
USHORT port;
sockaddr_in hSockAddr;
char website[50];
void initWSA();
void createSocket();
hostent* websiteInfo;
void getPort();
void connectSocket();
void cleanUp();

//Functions:
void initWSA(){
    if(WSAStartup(version, &info) == 0){
        cout << "WinSock initialization successful!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "WinSock initialization failed!" << endl;
    }
}
void createSocket(){
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(hSocket != INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout << "Socket Creation Successful!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Socket Creation Failed!" << endl;
    }
}
void getPort(){
    cout << "Enter the port number to connect to:" << endl;
}
void connectSocket(){
    if(connect(hSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&hSockAddr, sizeof(hSockAddr)) == 0){
        cout << "Connection to server successful!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Connection to server failed! error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
}

void cleanUp(){
    if(closesocket(hSocket) == 0){
        cout << "Socket Closure Successful!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Socket Closure Failed!" << endl;
    }
    if(WSACleanup() == 0){
        cout << "WinSock cleanup successful!\a" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "WinSock cleanup failed!\a" << endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Definitions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    initWSA();
    createSocket();
    cout << "IP Address of: " << "www.google.com" << " is: "<< gethostbyname("www.google.com") << endl;
    getPort();
    cin >> port;
    hSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hSockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    hSockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("www.google.com");
    connectSocket();
    cleanUp();
    return 0;
}
```

This is always what i get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qchs.png]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try searching for [winsock error codes, and their meanings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: `the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yup i saw the page but i didnt really understand what the error means: (Cannot assign requested address.)

Comment: @TZHX but they are both valid??

Comment: `inet_addr` doesn't do DNS lookups, it needs a "dotted-decimal" IP address, such as "127.0.0.1".

Comment: In addition, the return value of [gethostbyname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) isn't string containing the IP address - it is a pointer to a [hostent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, so there's no point in printing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you convert host address to ip,

[inet_addr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx) is for ip addresses:

> The inet_addr function ***converts a string containing an IPv4 dotted-decimal address*** into a proper address for the IN_ADDR structure.

instead of:

```
hSockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("www.google.com");
```

use:

```
struct hostent *he = gethostbyname("www.google.com");
memcpy(&hSockAddr.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[0], he->h_length);

// Or:
//hSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr *)(he->h_addr))->s_addr;
```

see here: [converting host to ip by sockaddr_in gethostname etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444197/converting-host-to-ip-by-sockaddr-in-gethostname-etc)

[edit]

As Remy Lebeau has written in comment, gethostbyname is depracated and getaddrinfo should be used instead, below is sample code using getaddrinfo:

```
  // Resolve host name
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  int rv;
  std::string str_port = std::to_string(port);
  if ((rv = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", str_port.c_str(), &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    std::cerr << "getaddrinfo: " << rv << ": " << gai_strerrorA(rv) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // Loop over all returnd addresses, first one that works is the one we want to use
  for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    createSocket();
    if (connect(hSocket, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
      cout << "Connection to server successful!" << endl;
      break;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Connection to server failed! error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
      closesocket(hSocket);
    }
  }
  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
```

Comment: **[`gethostbyname()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524.aspx) is deprecated**, you should be using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx) instead. And don't forget error handling, DNS lookups can fail.

Answer (score 0):

See [Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx), in this case:

> **WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL**
>   10049
>
> Cannot assign requested address.
>
> The requested address is not valid in its context. This normally results from an attempt to `bind` to an address that is not valid for the local computer. This can also result from `connect`, `sendto`, `WSAConnect`, `WSAJoinLeaf`, or `WSASendTo` when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).

Did you see your IP address output? I think it's not what you want.

I think you should see this example in order to get the IP address:

Winsock Programmer’s FAQ
Examples: [Get the Local IP Address(es)](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/ipaddr.html)